# Using Sitecore GraphQl in C# and send data to JSS

Tags: jss, sitecore-api, graphql

I am figuring out the `Sitecore GraphQL Query` where I need to use it as a query in my C# code (if that possible) where I just get all the items of a specific location in the Sitecore Tree. However, I may need to filter the item results based on a particular Field Value. And send the results to the `JSS frontend`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You should write a custom query and then in its implementation you can read the Field Value for the filtering

Comment: Why do you "need" to use GraphQL from C#? why not just use the Sitecore API?

Comment: @RichardSeal which Sitecore API do you mean? Am searching for a better performance way to query on Sitecore items, that's why I'm asking about GraphQL

Comment: _The_ Sitecore API, if you want the best performance, you should look at the [Content Search API](https://soen.ghost.io/a-re-introduction-to-the-contentsearch-api-in-sitecore-part-1/) - that will usually perform the best. Calling GraphQL from C# back end code makes no sense, the GraphQL implementation uses the Sitecore API internally, so you would be just adding an extra layer of processing.

Comment: @RichardSeal Thank you so much for your help